# KafkaConsumer code, wrapped in uwsgi, running in Docker, appears to be doing nothing

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, uwsgi, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to run KafkaConsumer code in uwsgi and within Docker container.

The code works outside of Docker/uwsgi, but once started in Docker, the uwsgi reports no errors (but it also does not lot neither to stdin/out, nor log file).

So, the issue is that this consumer does not commit anything to ES, and it also does not log anything within container. I am out of options, so I need some help.

I can not see why the uwsgi does not write / output no activity. The docker container contains no logs (I checked), and I can't seem to grasp why the multiprocessing Processes do not start. I did lazy-app config, so all workers should be spawned independently. The behaviour is the same if I run single or multiple processes, and it was the same in master / non-master mode, and file /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp_consumer.log never gets created.

## ini config:

```
;uWSGI instance configuration
[uwsgi]
ini = /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp_consumer.ini
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins = python3
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chdir = /opt/myapp_consumer/src
enable-threads = true
lazy-apps = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
close-on-exec = true
show-config = true
master = true
logfile = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp_consumer.log
logfile-chmod = 644
logfile-chown = www-data:www-data
wsgi-file = main.py
env = MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME=/opt/myapp_consumer
;end of configuration
```

## uwsgi log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12-debian (64bit) on [Sun Feb 25 23:53:51 2018] ***
compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 31 August 2017 21:02:04
os: Linux-4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Mon Nov 6 16:00:12 UTC 2017
nodename: ecf416b71ce0
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
chdir() to /opt/myapp_consumer/src
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xa3be40
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 415360 bytes (405 KB) for 8 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 8, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 9, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 10, cores: 2)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xa3be40 pid: 9 (default app)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xa3be40 pid: 7 (default app)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xa3be40 pid: 10 (default app)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xa3be40 pid: 8 (default app)
```

## myapp code

Note that myapp code is abbreviated for obscuring client data. However, I think the key of the problem lies within application method...

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import time
import multiprocessing
import requests
import json

from kafka import KafkaConsumer

class AConsumer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def run(self):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                 auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                                 consumer_timeout_ms=2000)
        consumer.subscribe(['mytopic'])

        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            for message in consumer:
                entry = json.loads(message.value)
                Transaction.commit(entry)

                if self.stop_event.is_set():
                    break

        consumer.close()

class Transaction:
    @staticmethod
    def commit(id, payload):
        sPayload = payload
        sHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        sEndpoint = 'http://localhost:9200/myapp/entries/
        response = requests.post(sEndpoint, data=sPayload, headers=sHeaders)
        logging.info(response.text)


def application(env, start_response):
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
                              ("Content-Encoding", "utf-8")])
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)s:%(name)s:%(thread)d:%(levelname)s:%(process)d:%(message)s',
        level=logging.DEBUG
    )

    tasks = [
        AConsumer()
    ]

    for t in tasks:
        t.start()
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  TERM=linux \
  MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME=/opt/myapp_consumer

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
  apt-utils \
  build-essential \
  git \
  python3 \
  python3-dev \
  python3-setuptools \
  python3-pip \
  uwsgi \
  uwsgi-plugin-python3 \
  && apt-get autoremove \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install xlwt
RUN pip3 install xlrd
RUN pip3 install kafka-python
RUN pip3 install -U uwsgi


# Copy our source files
COPY src ${MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME}/src
COPY config ${MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME}/config

RUN ln -s ${MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME}/config/myapp_consumer.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ${MYAPP_CONSUMER_HOME}/src


CMD ["/usr/bin/uwsgi", "--ini", "/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp_consumer.ini"]
```

Comment: There are two issues I have identified with this approach: I installed uwsgi both via pip3 and via apt-get and I think I have python version mismatch. When I used uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6 Docker image, then the issue disappeared so I suspect the problem is with the python versioning. However, I am looking for help on how to exactly debug this, to be really sure of the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue changing the type of bootstrap_server to list helped in my case. So, your kafkaConsumer might look like:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                             auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             consumer_timeout_ms=2000)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I however think there is something fishy going on with uwsgi: The app actually does not get started. I failed to find any traces online on how to properly configure app callable. So if I use Flask and say app = Flask(__name__) then it's all good. But - what happens exactly behind the scenes is the answer to my question.